# special grid layout in android

Tags: android, layout, user-interface

I've 4 large images in my android application.

I want to show them as below.

[image]

These images should have a same size in any android device, from 3" to 10" and...

How can I apply these layout?

Note that images are very large, and I'd like to have a flexible layout for this.

This is a XAML equivalent that works fine in windows phone

```
<Grid RowDefenitons="*,*" ColumnDefeniton="*,*">
    <ImageBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
    <ImageBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
    <ImageBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
    <ImageBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

This is a html equivalent:

```
<table style="width: 100%;height: 100%;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="1.jpg" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;"></td>
            <td><img src="1.jpg" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;"></td>
        </tr>        
        <tr>         
            <td><img src="1.jpg" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;"></td>
            <td><img src="1.jpg" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I've tried lots of samples in my android application, but non of them were ok for me.

This is a last result of my tries:

```
<TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="1">
        <TableRow>
            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ManagedTransactionsIcon"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp" />
            </FrameLayout>
            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/UnManagedTransactionsIcon"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp" />
            </FrameLayout>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/AlarmsIcon"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp" />
            </FrameLayout>
            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ReportsIcon"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp" />
            </FrameLayout>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

But it only works in 10" android devices on portrait mode only.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a final results of my tries which is working very good in any resolution:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/ManagedTransactionsIcon"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:minWidth="25px"
                android:minHeight="25px">
                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/UnManagedTransactionsIcon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:minWidth="25px"
                android:minHeight="25px">
                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/AlarmsIcon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:minWidth="25px"
                android:minHeight="25px">
                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/ReportsIcon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```